# How to add multi object from NSArray to one key of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a Object with some keys/values. After that, It was added into a array.

```
ContactAlphaB *contact = [ContactAlphaB contactWithFirstName:friendList.firstName lastName:friendList.lastName username:friendList.username country:friendList.country];
[_mucontacts addObject:contact];
```

Each contact have a country difference. I want to create a `NSDictionary` with key is `country` and value is contact in this array `_mucontacts`

Example: Inside `_mucontacts` I have 5 contact:

```
country of contact1 is Unites State.
country of contact2 is England.
country of contact3 is England.
country of contact4 is Unites State.
country of contact5 is Unites State.
```

How to I can create a `NSDictionary` with format:

```
{
    Unites State =     (
        "contact1",
        "contact4”,
        "contact5”
    );
    England =     (
        "contact2”,
        "contact3”
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand why you need to make a dictionary out of your items using the country as a key, however I am assuming its so you can easily grab a list of contacts based on country. If that is the case you could skip putting your contacts into a dictionary and just use a predicate to filter your existing array of objects like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.country ==[c] England"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

In this example SELF represents your Object Class and country is your property you are trying to filter by. You could also easily pass in an NSString instead of hard coding 'England' into the predicate.

Comment: Hi zfetters. How to I can add new key and value for NSmutabledictionary.
Because, I am using for loop to find and put it into my nsmutalbedictionary. So, it will get last country.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < arrCountry.count; i++) {
                NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.strcountry ==[c] %@", [arrCountry objectAtIndex:i]];
                NSArray *filteredArray = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
                if (filteredArray.count > 0) {
                    [mu_dictSection setObject:filteredArray forKey:[arrCountry objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }

Comment: it will insert England, not United State.
{
    England =     (
        "contact2”,
        "contact3”
    );
}

Comment: Do you understand me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the for loop you provided would loop through a list of countries and add a new array of contacts for that country with the country as its key. Is this not what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can have array values in a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary * dict = @{ "United States" : @[ "contact1", "contact4", "contact5" ] };
```

*or*

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [ NSMutableDictionary dictionary ] ;
[ dict 
    setValue:@[ "contact1", "contact4", "contact5" ]
      forKey:@"United States" ] ;
```

---

Looking up by key returns an array:

```
NSArray * contactsInUS = dict[@"United States"] ;
```

Comment: Are you really understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

Elements of an `NSDictionary` can be `NSArrays`:

```
// Create our indexed list of contacts (by country)
NSMutableDictionary *indexedContacts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// Iterate through the contacts
for (ContactAlphaB *contact in _mucontacts) {
    // Get the current list of contacts for the current contact's country
    NSMutableArray *contactsByCountry = [indexedContacts objectForKey:contact.country];
    // If the list doesn't exist for that country yet, create it
    if (!contactsByCountry) {
      contactsByCountry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      [indexedContacts setObject:contactsByCountry forKey:contact.country];
    }
    // Add the contact to the country list
    [contactsByCountry addObject:contact];
{

// Get list of contacts for England
NSArray *englishContacts = [indexedContacts objectForKey:@"England"];
for (ContactAlphaB *contact in englishContacts) {
  NSLog(@"%@", contact.username);
}
```

Comment: Because you are using for loop. So, it get last contact to add into nsdictionary.

Comment: Although I have 5 contacts. But, your code get only 2 contacts for 2 country. It is showing:
{
    Unites State =     (
        "contact5”
    );
    England =     (
        "contact3”
    );
}

Comment: I modified the code. Try now.

Comment: Yes, I will try it right now.

Comment: And now, it only get 1 country in NSDictionary

Comment: my Dictionary only 1 key and 1 value @@

Comment: Can you help me edit your code?

Comment: I tested the code, and it works.

Comment: Oh my god! Can you review your code and edit it?

Comment: I'm really sorry, It's work well. Thank you for your help.